# Dispatch source is only called when I do a NSLog() first

Tags: iphone, sockets, networking, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to use grand central dispatch in conjunction with bsd sockets to send an icmp ping. I add DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_WRITE and DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_READ as dispatch sources to read and write async.

So this is the method were I create the bsd socket and install the dispatch sources:

```
- (void)start
{
    int                     err;
    const struct sockaddr * addrPtr;

    assert(self.hostAddress != nil);

    // Open the socket.

    addrPtr = (const struct sockaddr *) [self.hostAddress bytes];

    fd = -1;
    err = 0;
    switch (addrPtr->sa_family) {
        case AF_INET: {
            fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP);
            if (fd < 0) {
                err = errno;
            }
        } break;
        case AF_INET6:
            assert(NO);
            // fall through
        default: {
            err = EPROTONOSUPPORT;
        } break;
    }

    if (err != 0) {
        [self didFailWithError:[NSError errorWithDomain:NSPOSIXErrorDomain code:err userInfo:nil]];
    } else {
        dispatch_source_t writeSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_WRITE, fd, 0, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0));
        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(writeSource, ^{
            abort(); // testing
            // call call method here to send a ping
        });
        dispatch_resume(writeSource);
        //NSLog(@"testout");

        dispatch_source_t readSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_READ, fd, 0, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0));
        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(readSource, ^{
            unsigned long bytesAvail = dispatch_source_get_data(readSource);
            NSLog(@"bytes available: %lu", bytesAvail);
        });
        dispatch_resume(readSource);
    }
}
```

You see the //NSLog(@"testout");? The funny thing is that the write block is only called when the //NSLog(@"testout"); is NOT commented out. This is very odd. I didn't test the read callback. The sending needs to be working first.

So what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error:

In newer SDKs dispatch sources are subject to automatic reference counting despite the fact that they are no Objective-C objects.

So when the start method is over ARC disposes the dispatch source and they never get called.

NSLog delays the end of the start method in a way that the dispatch source triggers before the source gets disposed.

Comment: dispatch sources are actually Objective-C objects in iOS 6 and later. 
See the GCD manpages or the GCD session from WWDC2012 for details.

Comment: @Alexander: So what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are kind of a bunch of things missing here. I'm not sure exactly which one is causing the weird behavior, but when I do all of the missing things, it seems to work "as expected" and my write event handler is called reliably and repeatedly. In general, there are a bunch of things you need to do when setting up a socket like this *before* passing it off to GCD. They are:

1. Create the socket
2. Bind it to a local address **(missing in your code)**
3. Set it to non-blocking **(missing in your code)**

Here is a little example I was able to put together in which the write handler gets called repeatedly, as expected:

```
int DoStuff()
{
    int fd = -1;

    // Create
    if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("cannot create socket");
        return 0;
    }

    // Bind
    struct sockaddr_in *localAddressPtr = (struct sockaddr_in *)malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    memset((char *)localAddressPtr, 0, sizeof(*localAddressPtr));
    localAddressPtr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    localAddressPtr->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    localAddressPtr->sin_port = htons(0);

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)localAddressPtr, sizeof(*localAddressPtr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed");
        return 0;
    }

    // Set non-blocking
    int flags;
    if (-1 == (flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0)))
        flags = 0;
    if (-1 == fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK))
    {
        perror("Couldnt set non-blocking");
        return 0;
    }


    // Do a DNS lookup...
    struct hostent *hp;
    struct sockaddr_in *remoteAddressPtr = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)); 

    // Fill in the server's address and data
    memset((char*)remoteAddressPtr, 0, sizeof(*remoteAddressPtr));
    remoteAddressPtr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    remoteAddressPtr->sin_port = htons(12345);

    // Look up the address of the server by name
    const char* host = "www.google.com";
    hp = gethostbyname(host);
    if (!hp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not obtain address of %s\n", host);
        return 0;
    }

    // Copy the host's address into the remote address structure
    memcpy((void *)&remoteAddressPtr->sin_addr, hp->h_addr_list[0], hp->h_length);

    dispatch_source_t writeSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_WRITE, fd, 0, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0));
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(writeSource, ^{
        // Send message
        const char* my_message = "the only thing we have to fear is fear itself.";
        unsigned long len = strlen(my_message);
        if (sendto(fd, my_message, len, 0, (struct sockaddr *)remoteAddressPtr, sizeof(*remoteAddressPtr)) != len) {
            perror("sendto failed");
            dispatch_source_cancel(writeSource);
        }
    });

    dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(writeSource, ^{
        close(fd);
        free(localAddressPtr);
        free(remoteAddressPtr);
    });

    dispatch_resume(writeSource);

    return 1;
}
```

NB: There's no way to dispose of the writeSource in my example without there being an error in a send operation. It's a trivial example...

My general theory on why `NSLog` triggers the handler to fire in your case, is that it keeps execution at or below *that* stack frame long enough for the background thread to come around and call the handler, but without that `NSLog`, your function returns, and something has a chance to die before the handler can get called. In fact, if you're using ARC it's probably the `writeSource` **itself** that is getting deallocated, since I don't see you making a strong reference to it anywhere outside the scope of this function. (My example captures a strong reference to it in the block, thus keeping it alive.) You could test this in your code by stashing a strong reference to `writeSource.`